# Can't get ubuntu one / update-manager to use system proxy settings

Tags: update-manager, settings

I set the network proxy as per the system settings GUI but this is not picked up by ubuntu one or update-manager - I just get failed to update repository information.

Even apt doesn't work. I then added a proxy into the config file manually in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` with:

```
Acquire:http { Proxy "http://whatever:1234"; };
```

I could then run apt-get successfully. But still not the two packages above. Why aren't the system settings working?

Comment: Did you click on *apply system wide* ?

Answer (score 1):

Backup this file.

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/apt.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf.bak
```

You can try editing the file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Add lines like:

- For proxy **without** authentication.

  ```
  Acquire::http::proxy "http://proxy_server:port/";
  ```
- For proxy **with** authentication.

  ```
  Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxy_server:port/";
  ```

Same way for other protocols like ftp, https etc.

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update.
```

Hope this helps.